# Scaling carousel centering selected div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a slider that displays 5 slides (squares). The selected slide is centered on the screen and it is bigger than the others. Users can click buttons to make the slider slide left or right selecting an adjacent square and centering it on the screen.
This is the HTML:

```js
const slider = document.querySelector(".slider");
const slideLeft = document.querySelector(".slide-left");
const slideRight = document.querySelector(".slide-right");
const getSelectedSquare = () => document.querySelector(".selected");

let translate = 0;

function changeSelectedClass(direction) {
  const selected = getSelectedSquare();

  const map = {
    left: selected.nextElementSibling,
    right: selected.previousElementSibling,
  }

  const nextSelected = map[direction];

  selected.classList.remove("selected");
  nextSelected.classList.add("selected");
}

function centerSelected() {
  const selected = getSelectedSquare();
  const { width, left } = selected.getBoundingClientRect();
  
  const distanceFromCenter = (window.innerWidth / 2) - left - (width / 2);
  translate += distanceFromCenter;

  slider.style.transform = `translateX(${translate}px)`;
}

slideRight.onclick = () => { changeSelectedClass("right"); centerSelected(); };

slideLeft.onclick = () => { changeSelectedClass("left"); centerSelected(); };
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
}

.square {
  width: 250px;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.square.selected {
  background: lightpink;
}

.square:not(.selected) {
  width: 200px;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="square"> 1 </div>
    <div class="square">2</div>
    <div class="square selected">3</div>
    <div class="square">4</div>
    <div class="square">5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-wrapper">
    <button class="btn slide-left">&#8678;</button>
    <button class="btn slide-right">&#8680;</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that at the moment the selected div is not centered correctly when a button is pressed and the slider slides. The code works fine if all the divs have the same dimensions, but when scaling comes into play I'm missing something.
I'm no expert at all in animations and if the approach I took is wrong I would rather rebuild it, than make adjustments to make it work as it is.
Additional requirements are that the dimentions of the squares should be dynamic (eg. 15vw), the distance between them should be the same (here I'm using flex gap) and the squares should become smaller and smaller the furthest away from the selected one (this is not implemented yet in the code sample).
Since I'm learning new stuff, I'd rather not use external libraries (that do that exact thing (I know)).

A codepen of the work until now: https://codepen.io/mtenti/pen/ExvNdZL

Comment: Could you set up working a codepen.io / demo of this? It makes it easier to debug vs just looking at the code.

Comment: I added the codepen :)

Comment: I seems to be working -- when I click the L or R buttons the squares move an the next box is in the middle of the viewport.  I do see a problem if you click more times than there are squares it breaks (beyond -1 or 6).  My suggestion is to not try to reinvent the wheel.  I know you don't want to use external, there are a bunch of slider  scripts that do this and more.   The other side of this is you need to debug the JavaScript and figure out all the bugs, when others have solved it already.  A good free script is: https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: Update: I do see the issue when scaled down. Try css grid and use Fraction Units (FR) https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/css-css-grid-layout-fr-unit